# Terraform bucket ACL with for_each

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, foreach, terraform

I'm trying to build multiple s3 buckets and each will have its own ACL configuration.

The problem is that I won't know the ID of each bucket until it is created and I need the ID in order to pass the ACL to be set.

When I run terraform validate with the code below there is no error. But after running the plan it tries to access the ID value within the values ​​I configured for each bucket and as ID does not exist it returns an error.

```
locals {
  bucket_settings = {
    bucket-code-pipeline  = {
        name              = "cache-codepipeline-${var.env}-bucket-01"
        acl               = "private"
    },
    bucket-alb            = {
        name              = "alb-logs-${var.env}-bucket-02"
        acl               = "private"
    }
  }
}


resource "aws_s3_bucket" "bucket" {
  for_each  = local.bucket_settings
  bucket    = each.value.name 
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket_acl" "acl" {
  for_each  = local.bucket_settings
  bucket    = local.bucket_settings[each.value.id]
  acl       = each.value.acl 
}
```

```
➜  s3 git:(master) ✗ terraform validate
Success! The configuration is valid.
```

```
➜  s3 git:(master) ✗ terraform plan
var.env
  Enter a value: dev

╷
│ Error: Unsupported attribute
│
│   on s3-buckets.tf line 37, in resource "aws_s3_bucket_acl" "acl":
│   37:   bucket    = local.bucket_settings[each.value.id]
│     ├────────────────
│     │ each.value is object with 2 attributes
│
│ This object does not have an attribute named "id".
```

I'd like to understand why I can't access the bucket ID through each `each.value.id`.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of

```
  bucket    = local.bucket_settings[each.value.id]
```

it should be

```
  bucket    = aws_s3_bucket.bucket[each.key].id
```

or

```
bucket    = each.value.name
```

Comment: worked thanks! 

That way every time I need to access an attribute of an object I need to pass the resource that is creating it and the value I need is that?